# Why might identical hard disks perform at different speeds?

Tags: hard-drive, performance, stress-test

I have just bought two WD 3TB Reds (WD30EFRX) for a FreeNAS box and whilst doing burn-in testing it seems like one is consistently taking about 10% longer than the other.

So far I've done: a `dd` read test of the whole device, a long SMART test and it's currently halfway through a `badblocks -wvs`. The second device is lagging behind the first on all of them.

I'm running these commands on Debian stable in two Konsole tabs. Is there a reason this could be considered normal behaviour or is it worth running the tests independantly? They're both plugged in to the LSI 2308 (IT mode) on a Supermicro X10SL7-F.

Edit:
So `badblocks` completed. Then I did a simultaneous read/write test on each drive in turn and the speeds were consistent: one drive is definitely 5-10% slower than the other. No problems were reported by `badblocks`or `smartctl`.

Comment: Are you sure they're both in SATA 6gb ports?

Comment: Silly-Checklist (maybe you have just done it): Did you check BIOS setting of the ports? Did the Hard disks have the same jumper settings?  Did you try to switch the HD position and to repeat the test (Unplug the cables from the HD side then switch them)? Do they have a different number of damaged sector? Try to see if there's a zone with bad block not consecutive: it can slow down the test... Good luck

Comment: @Spencer5051 As I said, they're both plugged into the LSI 2308 controller. All the connectors for this controller are the same speed.

Comment: @Hastur There were no reported SMART errors as a result of the `dd` read or the long SMART test. The `badblocks` is still running but as of roughly half way through there were no reported bad sectors.